# How to use Dapper with IDataErrorInfo Interface validations?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper, idataerrorinfo

I am new to ORM so please be calm to answer my question.
I have built a POCO admin class with Dapper attributes and Implemented IDataErrorInfo for validations on my Model classes
Here:

public partial class Admin:IDataErrorInfo
    {

```
    [Key]
    public long Admin_Id { get; set; }
    public string Admin_Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Verifying_Agent> Verifying_Agent { get; set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Admin_Name":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Admin_Name))
                        return "Admin Name is required";
                    break;
                case "Password":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                        return "Password is Required";
                    break;

            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

But when i excute Dapper.Simple CRUD library for Simple CRUD operation
i.e

```
conn= new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\SystemDB.db");
 var admit = conn.Get<Admin>("select * from Admin");
```

i get the following Error "Column or Database not exist"

While if I remove IDataErrorInfo implementaion the Error go away.
Is there something i am missing while using Dapper or there is a bug in This library?

Comment: There is an error in the line `var admit = conn.<Admin>("select * from Admin");`. Could you confirm if you mean `var admit = conn.Query<Admin>("select * from Admin");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a bug in the library and I've been unable to reproduce your problem despite creating an almost identical class and performing a similar query against a SQLite database.

This is the class I used:

```
class Post : IDataErrorInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Markdown { get; set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Title":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
                        return "Title is required";
                    break;
                case "Markdown":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Markdown))
                        return "Markdown is required";
                    break;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I queried the db:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Blog.sqlite"))
{
    var posts = conn.Query<Post>("SELECT * FROM Posts");
    Console.WriteLine(posts.Count() + " post(s) retrieved");
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing your problem but I'm fairly sure that it's not Dapper.

I'm mystified as to why removing the IDataErrorInfo interface would affect this error:

> Column or Database not exist

That sounds like the query should fail regardless of the type that you're trying to populate.

Comment: I agree there is no problem wtih the Dapper Library.
but im talking about Dapper.Simple CRUD library which contains builtin CRUD operations like Get, GetAll, Update etc